# Sublime text find only <? character

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2

Is there a way to get all content `<?` but not `<?php` or `<?=` in sublime text?

I tried `<? \n`, it doesn't give me the desired results.

Comment: Does `<\?(?!php|=)` as a regex work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search `<?` by regex, with [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
<\?(?!(php|=))
```